# parse geoJSON using bounding box and Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers

I have used Openlayers 3 to give me a bounding box extent and then make a WFS call to Geoserver using those extents and returning a geoJSON and it has worked perfectly, giving me the features within the bounding box from the complete dataset.

Now I have a geoJSON that already is a complete dataset and a local file and not coming back as WFS call. Is it possible to get select features from that geoJSON based off the OL3 bounding box function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [getFeaturesInExtent(extent)](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeaturesInExtent), after you read your local geojson file.

So this code should work for you:

```
vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
              title: 'Layer',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                  projection : 'EPSG:3857',
                 url: 'local_geojson_data.json'
})}) ; //layer viewing the whole data

var selected_features = vectorLayer.getSource.getFeaturesInExtent([minx, miny, maxx, maxy]);
//select only features in extent

selected_vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
              title: 'selected_Layer',
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                  features : selected_features
})}) ; //draw those features in a new layer
```

Comment: I am using v3.3.0 of OL3 and when I call 

geoJSONobject.features.getFeaturesInExtent('bbox extents')

it says "getFeaturesInExtent is not a function"
could this be because it is still experimental?

Comment: The GeoJSON object is not an OL3 class, just a simple, native JavaScript object. You have to load the features first in a vector source, and call `getFeaturesInExtent()` on the source object.

Comment: i've explained more my answer to give a better understanding